# Can I have an affinity between the hash of a service bus property and an instance of an Azure function

Tags: azure-functions

I am posting messages to an Azure Service Bus Topic. One of the custom properties will be named `recipientId` and contain a string.

I have a point of contention in the processing because I need to update a sequential number in a database row for that specific recipient. The update must be atomic along with other DB updates because I am not allowed to have missing numbers in the sequence.

However, I don't want multiple function instances trying to process data for the same recipientId at the same time and encountering DB deadlocks on the same row.

Is there a way to assign some kind of affinity to topic subscribers so I can guarantee messages for the same recipientId will always go to the same function instance?

In psuedo-code what I need is something like

```
  int hashCode = message.CustomProperties["sender"].GetHashCode();
  var function = Functions[hashCode % Functions.Count];
  function(message);
```

Obviously I cannot do this because the Azure function doesn't know how many instances there are running, so it would need to be something supported by Azure.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for 'message sessions'. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions

I'm not totally sure about your current topic-subscriptions design, but you can also filter messages based on provided custom properties.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters

Comment: @PeterMorris it's great that I could help :)